# Problem with CTE recursive query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I've the next question: Imagine you get the next query using the `WITH` statement (using a CTE recursive query):

The query is ommited due it's not necessary to display the problem

| id | from | prod | parent_id | lit | tip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ST01 | Chem | 22 | null | 1 |
| 2 | ST02 | Chem | 23 | null | 1 |
| 3 | ST01 | Gaso | 24 | null | 1 |
| 22 | Place1 | ST02 -> Place1 -> Gaso | 1 | 7 | 2 |
| 23 | Place1 | ST01 -> Place1 -> Chem | 2 | 13 | 2 |
| 24 | Place2 | ST01 -> Place2 -> Gaso | 3 | 55.2 | 2 |

I'd like to "compress" this table to get something similar to

| id | parent_info | lit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ST01 -> Place1 -> Chem | 13 |
| 2 | ST01 -> Place2 -> Gaso | 55.2 |
| 3 | ST02 -> Place1 -> Gaso | 7 |

What's the process to do after the CTE when you put the AS to achieve the last table?

Comment: It's really hard to improve a query you can't see. By guessing, `where lit is not null`.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting query can ve something similar to (taking into account that `liters_prod` is the generated query with CTE recursive query:

```sql
SELECT lp1.id, lp2.prod as parent_info, lp2.lit FROM liters_prod lp1 INNER JOIN liters_prod lp2 ON lp1.parent_id=lp2.id WHERE lp1.lit is not NULL;
```

I think this is the good response.